# Ignore some inherited properties in EF6 code first mapping(.NET4 not .NET4.5)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, ef-code-first, mapping

I'm using EF6 code first with .NET4(I should deliver the project on win xp so I couldn't configure it with .NET4.5) in a win Form project.

I have a BaseEntity class that all other entities inherited from it:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int X {get; set;} 
    public int Y {get; set;} 
}  
public class Calendar:BaseEntity
{
    // properties    
}
```

How could I Ignore X,Y properties in my all entities without writing following code for each entity?

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Calendar>()
            .Ignore(t => t.X)
            .Ignore(t => t.Y)
```

Note that I couldn't use `[NotMapped]` attribute because I'm using EF6 with .NET 4.

Answer (score 2):

Use `EntityTypeConfiguration`s in stead of `modelBuilder.Entity<>`:

```
abstract class BaseEntityMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<BaseEntity>
{
    public BaseEntityMapping()
    {
        this.Ignore(t => t.X);
        this.Ignore(t => t.Y);
    }
}

class CalendarMapping : BaseEntityMapping
{
    public CalendarMapping()
    {
        // Specific mappings
    }
}
```

And in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CalendarMapping());
```

Comment: So, I have to create Mapping class for each entity. I'm looking for a solution that, I write one time and it works for all entities, if possible.

Comment: You will be better off having mapping classes per entity. It takes some time to create them, but after that, it will for ever be much easier to find a specific mapping if you want to inspect or modify it. Otherwise, I don't see any possibility. The only alternative is to convert the properties to get/set methods.

Comment: As an alternative(get/set methods), do you mean I change {get; set;} to get { return _field;} set { _field = value}?

Comment: Programming Entity Framework: DbContext By Julia Lerman, Rowan Miller, Chapter6:
"It is possible to have properties in your class that do not map to the database. By con- vention, properties that do not have both a setter and a getter will not be part of the model. These are also known as transient properties.", so if I want have both set and get, I think this solution does not work.

Comment: I'm talking about *methods*: GetX(), SetX() etc. EF never maps methods. But it's a possible alternative. It may not work fir you if you need the properties X and Y for e.g. data binding. Then you better resort to mapping classes with a base class.