# Why EF6 not support ` ignore ` the property of the entity Property(complex property) Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

if the entity as

```
public class AddressDetail 
{
   public string Country{get;set;}
}

public class Order
{
    public AddressDetail AddressDetail{get;set;}
}
```

How ignore the `Oreder.AddressDetail.Country` property by Fluent API Not `[NotMap]`?

I found the solution for **EF6**，but I don't know Why Before EF6 have the function，EF6 don't have the function?

> **For EF5 and older:**
>   In the `DbContext.OnModelCreating` override for your context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Ignore(p => p.AddressDetails.Country);
```

> **For EF6:** You're out of luck. See [Mrchief's answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiRtW.png).

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting a `[NotMapped]` attribute on the property?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400719/ignore-some-inherited-properties-in-ef6-code-first-mapping-net4-not-net4-5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839131/telling-ef-6-to-ignore-a-private-property

Comment: @I want to know why`.[NotMapped]` is able to ignore the property.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this exception that only plain property expressions are allowed, so if you want to ignore the property of a property, you have to do it on the type of the outer property:

```
modelBuilder.Types<WhateverTheTypeOfResponseIs>()
    .Configure(c => c.Ignore(r => r.MobilePhone));
```

Though, i guess the proper syntax for EF6 would be:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<WhateverTheTypeOfResponseIs>()
    .Ignore(r => r.MobilePhone);
```